Location of adverb 'heute' in the sentence
In Duolingo, I wrote a sentence
Wir heute gehen ins Kaufhaus.

and they failed me, and the correct answer was
Wir gehen heute ins Kaufhaus.

I thought the location of the adverb 'heute' does not matter so much.
Was my initial answer so wrong?

The problem with the sentence

Wir heute gehen ins Kaufhaus.

is that heute is placed at position 2. But in a statement, this position is reserved for the verb. Which means that this sentence violates the verb-second rule, making it ungrammatical.
These are valid sentences:

Heute gehen wir ins Kaufhaus.


Wir gehen heute ins Kaufhaus.

because in both of these sentences the verb is at second position.
Now, sometimes a sentence seems to violate the verb-second rule, for example:

Die Vorführung heute habe ich mir nicht angeschaut.

Here, it seems that heute is at position 2, which would violate the verb-second rule. But this is actually not the case, because heute is an attribute of Die Vorführung, so the words Die Vorführung heute constitute the first part of the sentence, and the verb habe is the second part, so this is a valid German sentence.

One issue with Duo is that they don't always tell you the grammatical rules and you have to figure them out on your own. So it's a good idea to supplement Duo with grammar resources. The sites listed in the grammar section here are a good place to start.

PS. It may be worth mentioning that while German word order is more flexible than English in general, the verb second rule must be obeyed (almost always). Also, not every word order in English works in German, for example the English "Today we are going to the department store," puts the verb third, and that won't work in German. Finally, the verb second rule works for main clauses in statements. Yes/no question have use verb first: "Gehen wir heute ins Kaufhaus?" Also, subordinate clauses use a verb last rule. All this would be explained in detail by a good grammar resource.

If you want to use Duolingo, you need get used to the fact that it makes its own rules for what it considers right or wrong. You cannot discuss them. You just have to accept what Duolingo considers the correct answer even if it does not coincide with the actual usage of the language in question.
That said, in this specific case, Wir heute gehen ins Kaufhaus. is actually a correct German sentence, but the unusual position of the word heute conveys a very particular meaning with heute serving as a qualifier to wir instead of gehen. You could use it in a setting like:
Die Menschen früherer Jahrhunderte mussten dafür bis zum nächsten Markttag warten.
Wir heute gehen ins Kaufhaus.

(People in past centuries had to wait for market day for that. We, people of today, just go to the shopping center.)
It is not a correct translation for the simple statement: "We're going to the shopping center today."
